# How do I convert DiffTime to NominalDiffTime?

Tags: haskell, haskell-time

Using the time library (time-1.5), I have a constant, e.g. 1 second. I don't see a way to create a NominalDiffTime, so I have created a DiffTime:

```
twoSeconds = secondsToDiffTime 2
```

Now I'd like to interact with a UTCTime:

```
now <- getCurrentTime
let twoSecondsAgo = addUTCTime (-twoSeconds) now
```

Which of course doesn't type check because addUTCTime expects a NominalDiffTime in argument 1 and I have passed a DiffTime. How do I convert between the two types? Or how can I create a NominalDiffTime of 2 seconds?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`NominalDiffTime` and `DiffTime` both have `RealFrac` instances and thus both `Fractional` and `Real` instances.

You can convert either of them to the other by

```
fromRational . toRational
```

Which has type `(Real a, Fractional c) => a -> c`. This is a very common thing to do, and is provided in the [standard prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html).

```
realToFrac     :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
realToFrac      =  fromRational . toRational
```

`DiffTime` and `NominalDiffTime` both have `Num` and `Fractional` instances. This means you can use both [integer and floating literals](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#numeric-literals) in place of either of them. All of the following work without any additional ceremony.

```
addUTCTime (-2)
addUTCTime 600
addUTCTime 0.5
```

Comment: `toRational` can potentially be a very expensive operation because it needs to compute `gcd` for numerator and denominator. This will also work: `fromIntegral . diffTimeToPicoseconds :: DiffTime -> NominalDiffTime`.

Answer (score 13):

Since `NominalDiffTime` is an instance of `Num`, you can create it with `fromInteger`.

```
>>> fromInteger 1 :: NominalDiffTime
1s
```

Comment: Due to how numeric literals work, you can just write `1 :: NominalDiffTime`. `1` already has type `Num a => a`. http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#numeric-literals

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just thinking about converting from non-literal integer. Thank you for pointing this out.